# Optimize update or push in huge array

Tags: javascript

I have huge array (~200-300k objects) and already populated array which can be any size. When both arrays are small there is no performance issues, however when both of them get bigger updating the value takes a lot of time.

What's is the fastest way to update object in `array1` if exists in `array2` with his values ?

Currently tried with both `.splice()` and `array[index]` with finding the index before that based on a key but this takes huge time, like a minute or 2.

```
let i = this.array2.length;
while (i--) {
    const row = this.array2[i];
    let existingSensorIndex = array1.findIndex(s => s.id === row.id);
    let node = this.convertToObject(row);

    if (existingSensorIndex !== -1) {
        array1.splice(existingSensorIndex, 1, node);
    } else {
        array1.push(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered not using arrays and instead using an object, as keys are indexed? (Key could be your "id" value, so when you want to see if it exists, you just see if `object2[id]` exists.)

Comment: Have you considered using a map instead of an array? [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Actually no, good catch :)

Comment: The more you have in the `array1`, `findIndex` gets potentially worse as it does a linear search. A map or object can do a direct lookup on your id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Lodash:

```
_.unionBy(arr1, arr2, function(a){return a.id;});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why it's faster?

Comment: It won't be faster as compared to fetching from a map. It gives an advantage of filtering through nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but using `for` and sparse arrays may do the trick. Consider the following:

```js
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < 200000; i++) array1[i * 2] = Math.random();
for (i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) array2[i * 3] = Math.random();
var updates = 0;

console.time();

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  if (array2[i]) {
    updates++;
    array2[i] = array1[i];
  }
}

console.timeEnd();
console.log(updates, "updates");
```

On my computer, this updates 133k rows of a 2M row array in 1.5s